# Geting latest "value" of secondary identifier

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

i need to get into select last values (with highest `IDa`) with specific identifier (`IDb`).

For example - input:

```
|IDa|IDb| text
================
| 1 | 1 | What
| 2 | 2 | code
| 3 | 1 | should
| 4 | 2 | I
| 5 | 2 | write
| 6 | 3 | here
| 7 | 2 | ?
```

wanted output:

```
|IDa|IDb| text
================
| 3 | 1 | should
| 7 | 2 | ?
| 6 | 3 | here
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If IDa is set to auto_increment you can use a self join

```
select t.*
from t 
join (select max(IDa) IDa,IDb from t group by IDb ) t1
using(IDa,IDb) /* is equivalent to on(t.IDa = t1.IDa and t.IDb = t1.IDb)  */
order by t.IDb
```

Also in your expected result set you have mentioned `what` for IDb 1 and according to your question there should be the word `should` because its the last one for IDb 1

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec22bb/3)

Comment: +1 - although, personally, I think USING is confUSING